# In what movie did a blind man tell this story

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm trying to remember what movie I watched where an old blind man (I think he was the grandfather of the main character, but I'm not sure), at one point tells this story:

This is just the gist of it, I can't remember most of it:

Once upon a time, a man (probably poor) falls in love with a princess. She says: "Sure, but you have to stand outside of my castle for 1000 nights." He does so, and he suffers through rain, hunger, etc... until he he gets used to it. On the 999th night, he looks at here, and leaves.

After the blind man tells the story, he says "Don't ask me what it means. I don't know."

Also, if you could tell me where this story comes from(or if it was written for the movie), that'd be great.

**Edit**

Thanks Will, I found the story. For some reason it stuck with me, and it was all I remembered about the film

> Once upon a time a king gave a feast 
>           and there were all the most beautiful 
>           princesses of the realm. Basta, one 
>           of the guards, saw the king's 
>           daughter: she was the loveliest of 
>           all! And he immediately fell in love 
>           with her. But what could a poor 
>           soldier do compared with a king's 
>           daughter?!...One day he managed 
>           to meet her and told her he couldn't 
>           live without her. The princess was so 
>           struck by the depth of his feeling 
>           that she said to the soldier  'If you 
>           will wait a hundred days and a 
>           hundred nights beneath my balcony, 
>           then in the end I'll be yours.' 
>           Christ, the soldier ran off there and 
>           waited! One day, two days, 
>           ten, twenty...Every night she looked 
>           out of her window, but he never 
>           budged. Come rain, wind, snow, never 
>           budged! The birds shat on him and the 
>           bees ate him alive! After ninety 
>           nights he was gaunt and pale and 
>           tears streamed from his eyes but he 
>           couldn't hold them back. He didn't 
>           even have the strength to sleep any 
>           more. The princess kept watch...And 
>           on the ninety-ninth night, the 
>           soldier got up, picked up his chair 
>           and left!

Comment: Do you know how old the film was, and what language and country it was from?

Comment: It was English, not sure about the others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [Cinema Paradiso](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095765/), (1988).  The old projectionist at the movie theater, Alfredo, loses his vision when the highly flammable nitrate film catches fire, and the young protagonist, Toto, does stand outside a girl's house every night after work to prove his love.  It could have been because of a story Alfredo told him, but I don't remember for sure.